# Toggle button switches through case statements with button debouncing

Tags: arduino-uno, led, button, millis, debounce

The overview of my code is that I want a toggle button to be pushed and each button push will move the code to the next case statement. In each case statement, there will be different LED functions. I need help with a few things

1. I need help with blinking 4 of the LEDs continuously with 100ms pause in case 1. Because it is not in the main loop, I am having trouble getting the 4 LEDs to switch on and off. Normally, I could just have a simple code that turns it on, then compares previous to last and if different, turns it off, and this continues.
2. I need the code to go back to case 0 once the button has been held for 2 seconds.
3. I cannot get my button debounce code to work from case 0 to case 1. If I add the debounce code in case 0 how I have it in the rest of the cases, it wont run through the rest of the cases.
   Below is the code:

```
//LED variables for left turn signal OUT
int LED_1 = 2; 
int LED_2 = 3;
int LED_3 = 4;
int LED_4 = 5; 

//LED variables for right turn signal OUT
int LED_5 = 6;
int LED_6 = 7;
int LED_7 = 8;
int LED_8 = 9;

//break signal OUT
int BS_OUT = A5;

//reverse signal OUT
int RS_OUT = 10;

//toggle switch button between different modes
int toggle_IN = A4;

//switch case statement variable for togglemodes
int toggleState = 0;

//variables to see if the toggle button has been pressed or not
boolean oldSwitchStateToggle = LOW;
boolean newSwitchStateToggle = LOW;

//true or false to save whether button has been pressed for switching case statements 
bool enabledToggle;

//debounce time to take care of button bouncing
const int debounce = 100; //ms

//time for holding a current time of millis()
unsigned long t = 0;



void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //toggle button input
  pinMode(toggle_IN, INPUT);

  //led outputs
  pinMode(LED_4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_8, OUTPUT);


}

void loop() 
{
   //checking to see if toggle button has been pushed 
   newSwitchStateToggle = digitalRead(toggle_IN);
   if(newSwitchStateToggle != oldSwitchStateToggle)
  {
    if(newSwitchStateToggle == HIGH)
    {
      //enabling toggle for if statements
      enabledToggle = true;
      //case switch for flow through 4 different LED output options 
      toggleButtonState();
      
    }
    else
    enabledToggle = false;
    oldSwitchStateToggle = newSwitchStateToggle;
  }
}

void toggleButtonState()
{
  unsigned long nowToggle = millis(); 
  switch (toggleState)
  {

    case 0:
    Serial.println("0000");
          if(enabledToggle)
          {
            digitalWrite(LED_1, HIGH);
            t = nowToggle;
            toggleState = 1;
          }

          break; 
          
    case 1:
    Serial.println("1111"); 
          if(enabledToggle)
          {
            digitalWrite(LED_1, LOW);
            digitalWrite(LED_2, HIGH);
            //alows going to next state after 100ms for button debounce
            if(nowToggle - t > debounce)
            {
              toggleState = 2;
              t = nowToggle;
            }
          }
       
          break;

     case 2:
     Serial.println("2222"); 
          if(enabledToggle)
          {
            digitalWrite(LED_2, LOW);
            digitalWrite(LED_3, HIGH);
            if(nowToggle - t > debounce)
            {
              toggleState = 3;
              t = nowToggle;
            }
          }
          
          break;
          
     case 3:
     Serial.println("3333"); 
         if(enabledToggle)
          {
            digitalWrite(LED_3, LOW);
            digitalWrite(LED_4, HIGH);
            if(nowToggle - t > debounce)
            {
              toggleState = 4;
              t = nowToggle;
            }
          }
          break;
          
     case 4:
     Serial.println("44444"); 
          if(enabledToggle)
          {
            turnOffLeds();
            if(nowToggle - t > debounce)
            {
              toggleState = 0;
              t = nowToggle;
            }
          }
          break;
         
  }
}

void turnOffLeds()
{
  digitalWrite(LED_1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED_2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED_3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED_4, LOW);
}
```

updated code: trying to add in debounce but it will not work

```
int LED_1 = 2; 
int LED_2 = 3;
int LED_3 = 4;
int LED_4 = 5; 


int LED_5 = 6;
int LED_6 = 7;
int LED_7 = 8;
int LED_8 = 9;


//toggle switch button between different modes
int toggle_IN = A4;

//switch case statement variable for togglemodes
int toggleState = 0;

//variables to see if the toggle button has been pressed or not
boolean oldSwitchStateToggle = LOW;
boolean newSwitchStateToggle = LOW;

//true or false to save whether button has been pressed for switching case statements 
bool enabledToggle;

//debounce time to take care of button bouncing
const int debounce = 100; //ms

//time for holding a current time of millis()
unsigned long t = 0;

int ledBlinkState = LOW;

unsigned long prevBlinkMillis = 0;

const int blinkInterval = 150;

bool state1 = false;
bool state2 = false;
bool state3 = false;
bool state4 = false;
bool state0 = false;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //toggle button input
  pinMode(toggle_IN, INPUT);

  //led outputs
  pinMode(LED_4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_8, OUTPUT);


}

void loop() 
{
  unsigned long nowToggle = millis(); 
  Serial.print("NOWWWWWW");
  Serial.println(nowToggle);
   //checking to see if toggle button has been pushed 
   newSwitchStateToggle = digitalRead(toggle_IN);
   if(newSwitchStateToggle != oldSwitchStateToggle)
   {
    t = nowToggle;
    Serial.print("TIMEEEEE");
    Serial.println(t);
    if(newSwitchStateToggle == HIGH)
    {
      if(nowToggle - t > debounce)
      {
        //enabling toggle for if statements
        enabledToggle = true;
        //case switch for flow through 4 different LED output options 
        toggleButtonState();
      }
      
    }
    else
    enabledToggle = false;
    oldSwitchStateToggle = newSwitchStateToggle;
  }

  unsigned long currentBlinkMillis = millis();
  
  if(state0 == true)
  {
    digitalWrite(LED_5, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED_6, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED_7, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED_8, HIGH);
    
    if(currentBlinkMillis - prevBlinkMillis >= blinkInterval)
    {
      prevBlinkMillis = currentBlinkMillis;
      if(ledBlinkState == LOW)
      {
        ledBlinkState = HIGH;
      }
      else
      {
        ledBlinkState = LOW;
      }
      digitalWrite(LED_1, ledBlinkState);
      digitalWrite(LED_2, ledBlinkState);
      digitalWrite(LED_3, ledBlinkState);
      digitalWrite(LED_4, ledBlinkState);
    }
  }
  
  if(state1 == true)
  {
    digitalWrite(LED_1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED_2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED_3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED_4, HIGH);
    
    if(currentBlinkMillis - prevBlinkMillis >= blinkInterval)
    {
      prevBlinkMillis = currentBlinkMillis;
      if(ledBlinkState == LOW)
      {
        ledBlinkState = HIGH;
      }
      else
      {
        ledBlinkState = LOW;
      }
      digitalWrite(LED_5, ledBlinkState);
      digitalWrite(LED_6, ledBlinkState);
      digitalWrite(LED_7, ledBlinkState);
      digitalWrite(LED_8, ledBlinkState);
    }
  }

  if(state2 == true)
  {
    if(currentBlinkMillis - prevBlinkMillis >= blinkInterval)
    {
      prevBlinkMillis = currentBlinkMillis;
      if(ledBlinkState == LOW)
      {
        ledBlinkState = HIGH;
      }
      else
      {
        ledBlinkState = LOW;
      }
      digitalWrite(LED_1, ledBlinkState);
      digitalWrite(LED_2, ledBlinkState);
      digitalWrite(LED_3, ledBlinkState);
      digitalWrite(LED_4, ledBlinkState);
      digitalWrite(LED_5, ledBlinkState);
      digitalWrite(LED_6, ledBlinkState);
      digitalWrite(LED_7, ledBlinkState);
      digitalWrite(LED_8, ledBlinkState);
    }
  }
  
  if(state3 == true)
  {
    digitalWrite(LED_1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED_2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED_3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED_4, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED_5, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED_6, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED_7, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED_8, HIGH);
  }
  
  if(state4 == true)
  {
    turnOffLeds();
  }
  
}

void toggleButtonState()
{
  switch (toggleState)
  {

    case 0:
    Serial.println("0000");
          if(enabledToggle)
          {
            turnOffLeds();
            state4 = false;
            state0 = true;
            toggleState = 1;
          }

          break; 
          
    case 1:
    Serial.println("1111"); 
          if(enabledToggle)
          {
            turnOffLeds();
            state0 = false;
            state1 = true;
            toggleState = 2;
          }
       
          break;

     case 2:
     Serial.println("2222"); 
          if(enabledToggle)
          {
            turnOffLeds();
            state1 = false;
            state2 = true;
            toggleState = 3;
          }
          
          break;
          
     case 3:
     Serial.println("3333"); 
         if(enabledToggle)
          {
            turnOffLeds();
            state2 = false;
            state3 = true;
            toggleState = 4;
          }
          break;
          
     case 4:
     Serial.println("44444"); 
          if(enabledToggle)
          {
            turnOffLeds();
            state3 = false;
            state4 = true;
            toggleState = 0;
          }
          break;
         
  }
}

void turnOffLeds()
{
  digitalWrite(LED_1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED_2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED_3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED_4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED_5, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED_6, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED_7, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED_8, LOW);
}
```

Comment: `1.` the toggleButtonState() should not contain any LED code ... it should only set a flag ... the blink code should be inside `loop()` and be activated by the flag

Comment: `2.` do button detection at begining of `loop()` ... the button code should only set a flag, nothing more

Comment: `3.` ... read `2.`

Comment: 1. So for example, I would be in case 1, and it would set a variable to true. Then in the loop, have an if statement to where if that variable is true, then it will loop through that blinking LED code?

Comment: yes ... the `loop()` repeats many times a second ... use `millis()` to blink ... see `blinkWithoutDelay` example sketch

Comment: @jsotola I got the flagging figure out and my code works great for blinking LEDs. I am now having trouble with getting the debounce code to work. I have it in my updated code but it does not work. I am trying to incorporate it around my button clicking in the loop(). When looking at it on my serial moniter, "t" is holding nowToggle every instance and not holding it at a single value.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you start with an existing library to do the "button debouncing" and "long button press" detection.

The [EasyButton](https://github.com/evert-arias/EasyButton) library on github and via the Arduino IDE library manager has potential.

Here is a test sketch which shows the "button detection" part of your requirement.

If you were to add a variable to represent "state", this code could be adapted to control a `case` statement bases on state.

```cpp
// Sketch uses 3286 bytes (10%) of program storage space.
// Global variables use 357 bytes (17%) of dynamic memory.
#include <EasyButton.h>

// EasyButton(uint8_t pin, 
//            uint32_t debounce_time = 35, 
//            bool pullup_enable = true, 
//            bool active_low = true)
EasyButton button(2);

void onPressed(){
  // Your code here to INCREMENT a "state counter".
  Serial.println("Button pressed");
}

void onPressedForDuration(){
  // Your code here to SET the "state counter" to 0.
  Serial.println("Button pressed for duration");
}

void setup(){

  // Test output to serial monitor.
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Initialize the button.
  button.begin();

  // Add the callback function to be called when the button is pressed.
  button.onPressed(onPressed);

  // Add the callback function to be called when the button is pressed
  // for at least the given time.
  button.onPressedFor(2000, onPressedForDuration);

}

void loop(){

  // Continuously read the status of the button.
  button.read();

}
```

Comment: I would have done it this way, but I am going to transfer this into the eclipse compiler. I am staying away from arduino made libraries. I am trying to find a way to look at what is going on in the background of the easybutton.h. Do you know where I could find this?

Comment: @Myles - You can look at the EasyButton source code to see how it works: https://github.com/evert-arias/EasyButton/tree/main/src

Answer (score 0):

I answered how to do a mode switch with just one button many many years ago.  Make use of it what you will... it's just a sample skeleton. Here is the code I used:

```
/*
 Using a single switch to select between 3 modes
*/
// Schematic: http://www.pwillard.com/files/mode4.jpg
//===============================================================
// Global Variables & Constants
//===============================================================
 
const int ledPinOne = 2; // LED1 ANODE
const int ledPinTwo = 4; // LED2 ANODE
const int ledPinThree = 7; // LED3 ANODE
const int modePin = 13; // Active HIGH, held low by 4.7K
 
int mode = 0; // Selector State (Initial state = ALL OFF)
int val = 0; // Pin 13 HIGH/LOW Status
int butState = 0; // Last Button State
int modeState = 0; // Last Mode State
boolean debug = 1; // 1 = Print Serial Enabled / 0 = disabled
 
//===============================================================
// SETUP
//===============================================================
void setup () {
 pinMode(ledPinOne, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(ledPinTwo, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(ledPinThree, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(modePin, INPUT);
 if (debug){
 Serial.begin(9600);
 Serial.print("Initial Mode: ");
 Serial.println(mode);
 Serial.print("Setup Complete\n");
 }
}
 
//===============================================================
// Main Loop
//===============================================================
void loop() {
 
 val = digitalRead(modePin);
 
 // If we see a change in button state, increment mode value
 if (val != butState && val == HIGH){
 mode++;
 }
 
 butState = val; // Keep track of most recent button state
 
 // No need to keep setting pins *every* loop
 if (modeState != mode){
 
 // If no keys have been pressed yet don't execute
 // the switch code below
 // if (mode != 0) {
 
 switch ( mode ) {
 //case 1 is actually handled below as default
 
case 2:
 digitalWrite(ledPinOne, LOW);
 digitalWrite(ledPinTwo, HIGH);
 showState();
 break;
 case 3:
 digitalWrite(ledPinTwo, LOW);
 digitalWrite(ledPinThree, HIGH);
 showState();
 break;
 default:
 mode = 1;
 // loop back to 1 by default, seems redundant but
 // it also handles the "mode is > 3" problem
 digitalWrite(ledPinThree, LOW);
 digitalWrite(ledPinOne, HIGH);
 showState();
 break;
 } // end switch
// } // end of "if mode = 0" check
 } // end of ModeState check
 modeState = mode; // Keep track of mode recent mode value
 delay(10); // slow the loop just a bit for debounce
}
 
//===============================================================
// Subroutine
//===============================================================
void showState() {
 if (debug){
 Serial.print("Mode: ");
 Serial.println(mode);
 }
}
```